# How to debug why a database trigger is not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My first two `IF` statements work just fine (I've tested them), but for some reason the `ELSE IF` statement won't fire. I've tried different setups for the entire `ELSE IF` statement, different  arrangements with the `@DiscountPercent`, and putting the `IF` statements in a different order, but nothing works. It all results in .3 when it needs to be 30. Can someone please point me in the direction of where I can learn about what I'm doing wrong?

```
USE MyGuitarshop

GO

CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE
    ON Products
    FOR UPDATE, INSERT

AS

DECLARE
    @DiscountPercent int;

BEGIN

SET @DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM INSERTED);

IF @DiscountPercent < 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW 528732,'Discount Percent cannot be less than 0.',1;
    END;

IF @DiscountPercent > 100 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW 528733,'Discount Percent cannot be greatter than 100%.',1;
    END;

ELSE IF @DiscountPercent < 1 
        UPDATE Products
            SET @DiscountPercent = ((SELECT DiscountPercent FROM INSERTED) * 100)
            WHERE ProductID IN (Select ProductID FROM Inserted);

END;

GO

UPDATE Products
    SET DiscountPercent = .3
        WHERE ProductID = 1;

GO

USE MyGuitarShop

SELECT * FROM Products
```

Comment: You need to pull the value from the INSERTED table. The values reflecting the change are in a table that is available to you in your trigger. For extra credit you could handle the case when multiple statements are batched, however, that is probably beyond the scope of work be asked of you.

Comment: I think in your case you should use `Instead of Insert , Update` , and you should check the value from the `Inserted` table .

Comment: Is this moving in the right direction? 


IF  
 (SELECT 
  DiscountPercent
   FROM
    Products_UPDATE JOIN Inserted
   ON
    Products_UPDATE.DiscountPercent = Inserted.DiscountPercent) 
   FROM
    Products.ProductID = Inserted.ProductID) < 1 

 SET @DiscountPercent = (@DiscountPercent * 100);
 
END;

Comment: WHen working in SQL Server you definitely need to consider multiple records being handled. Do not learn to do this by setting the value of a scalar variable to a field in inserted, it can contain multiple records. Don't learn to do this incorrectly.

Comment: This is an idiotic exercise. Triggers should not "auto-correct" input data. And when you have a fixed input range, a `CHECK` constraint is far more appropriate.

Comment: I.e. Imagine in the real world that you apply a range of percentage discounts. For one customer, you're particularly frugal - you only want to offer them a `0.5%` discount. Your trigger suddenly magnifies that into a `50%` discount. That's not good.

Comment: .5 is 50%. .05 would be 5%.

Comment: Triggers are very translucent and often times are signs of afterthought patchwork. I am a bit biased and don't like them, however, they are good mechanisms to understand because you will most likely run into systems that rely heavily on a triggered architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!!!! This is what the code needs to be to work:

```
USE MyGuitarshop

GO

CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE
    ON Products
    FOR UPDATE, INSERT

AS

DECLARE
    @DiscountPercent int;

BEGIN

SET @DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM INSERTED);

IF @DiscountPercent < 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW 528732,'Discount Percent cannot be less than 0.',1;
    END;

IF @DiscountPercent > 100 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW 528733,'Discount Percent cannot be greatter than 100%.',1;
    END;

ELSE
    UPDATE Products
        SET DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM INSERTED) * 100
            FROM Products
                Join Inserted
                    On Products.ProductID = Inserted.ProductID
            WHERE (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM INSERTED) < 1

END;

GO

UPDATE Products
    SET DiscountPercent = .3
        WHERE ProductID = 4;

GO

USE MyGuitarShop

SELECT * FROM Products
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two special tables that you have access to within the stored procedure. The tables can be examined to reflect the state of the data. Be sure to understand that multiple operations can be batched for certain circumstances.

[Trigger - Inserted and Deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables)

Comment: Multiple records should 100% of teh time be handled statement . No excuses. Generally it should be a set-based statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of `DiscountPercent` from `INSERTED` table , then check it  :

```
DECLARE
    @DiscountPercent int;
Begin
SET @DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM INSERTED);
.
.
.
```

That will work when `Update/Insert` one row , if there is more than 1 row `Updated/Inserted` then you need to use another way to get all the values.

Comment: Wonderful! This is what it needed! Thank you so much. I can't believe I forgot to set the value to pull from the inserted table. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops. Spoke too soon. This made it so the errors are triggered, but the third IF statement doesn't work.

Comment: @Krystianya what this for? `ELSE IF @DiscountPercent < 1 
    SET @DiscountPercent = (@DiscountPercent * 100);`

Comment: If the entered discount percent is a less than one (.2, for example) the trigger is supposed to make it a whole number. So, 20 instead of .2. Every line of code works now except that one.

Comment: The trigger does not update the table in the end of your trigger

Comment: I added an update statement, but it's still not working

Comment: It's still not working. I've tried different iterations, wordings, placements. I just don't understand why the last IF won't trigger.

I've got to leave for a class, but I'll be back in about 3 hours to continue working on this.

Comment: I've tried different setups with the ID in the code, but it kicks back errors every time. The code runs without the ID, it just doesn't fire the ELSE IF portion of the trigger statement.

Comment: This is fundamentally broken. It assumes that `inserted` contains exactly one row. That's a bad assumption. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows and triggers need to be written to cope with all of those situations. Ideally, by being written set based. Less ideally by using some form of looping construct. But *definitely* not, as here, by selecting some *arbitrary* value from one row into a scalar variable and ignoring the other rows.